# Как оптимизировать данный кусок кода?

Tags: php, yii2

yii2, рендерю view записи, также нужно добавлять кнопки "вперед" и "назад", для навигации по записям.

все сделал, выглядит так:

```
    public function actionView($id)
    {
//        $model = Images::findOne(['id' => $id]);
        $next = $id;
        $prev = $id;
        $all = Images::find()->all();
        foreach ($all as $key => $item) {
            if ($item['id'] == $id){
                $model = $item;
                if (array_key_exists($key + 1, $all)){
                    $next = $all[$key + 1]['id'];
                }
                if (array_key_exists($key - 1, $all)){
                    $prev = $all[$key - 1]['id'];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!$model || !$id){
            throw new HttpException(404, '404');
        }
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $model,
            'next' => $next,
            'prev' => $prev,
        ]);
    }
```

это работает, но при большом количестве записей страницы грузятся по 10+ секунд, а это неприемлимо.

как переписать данный кусок кода? по сути мне нужно просто узнать id соседних элементов, но пока я ничего другого не придумал.

Comment: А сделать парочку запросов на выборку того, что меньше и больше текущего $id с указанием LIMIT не пробовал? Алгоритм примерно такой:
1. Выбрать первую запись для которой выполняется условие id < $id (используй сортировку по убыванию id и limit 1)
2. Выбрать записи для которых id >= $id с limit 2 с сортировкой по возрастанию id и limit 2 Первая выборка дает тебе предыдущую модель, а вторая - текущую и следующую.
И вроде как для предыдущей и слеудющей тебе нужны только id-шники.

Comment: не пробовал. приведите пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: просто я не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Вы делаете запрос на получение данных по картинкам из БД?

Comment: да, для основной записи.
для соседних записей - нет.

Comment: 1. Выбрать первую запись для которой выполняется условие id < $id (используй сортировку по убыванию и limit 1)
2. Выбрать записи для которых id >= $id с limit 2 с сортировкой по возрастанию и limit 2

Первая выборка дает тебе предыдущую модель, а вторая - текущую и следующую.
И вроде как для предыдущей и слеудющей тебе нужны только id-шники.

Comment: пример кода, пожалуйста, иначе я не могу считать данный алгоритм рабочим, т.к. в моем представлении кода он стопорится на первом же шаге

Comment: @echmel, на другом ресурсе мне предложили то же сделать самое, но с приведением кода. ваш алгоритм был верен. спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать с помощью трех запросов (или одним при необходимости оптимизации количества запросов к БД)

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    if ($id === null || !(($model = Images::findOne(['id' => $id])) instanceof Images)) {
        throw new HttpException(404, '404');
    }

    $query = Images::find()->select(['id'])->limit(1);
    $next = $query->where(['>', 'id', $id])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_ASC])->scalar();
    $prev = $query->where(['<', 'id', $id])->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])->scalar();

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
        'next' => $next,
        'prev' => $prev,
    ]);
}
```